# Sort DataFrame Columns individually

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have seen many examples about how to sort a DataFrame based on some specific columns.

What I want to achieve is to sort Columns DataFrame individually, independently of each other. See the example below.

**Input**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| Column1    | Column2      | Column 3   |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|        61  |       5      |    9       |
|        14  |       16     |    8       |
|        26  |       27     |    7       |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| Column1    | Column2      | Column 3   |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|        14  |       5      |    7       |
|        26  |       16     |    8       |
|        61  |       27     |    9       |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Any clue how can I achieve this?

Comment: A dataframe is a set of rows , in the above case there is no notion of row. Please explain the reason for sorting columns independently.You could very well keep columns in seperate dataframes.

Comment: interesting task although I think such a representation would brake a basic principle of spark which is every row is the basic element of an RDD. If (61, 5, 9) -> ROW1 then (14, 5, 7) is not ROW1 anymore. How you would manage such a case?

Comment: @Raghavan, you mean to say, treat each column as a single DF and then maybe merge them into a single DF?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis yep, you are right. Seems like treat each Column as a single DataFrame would be a good option, is not?

Comment: @dbustosp Yes, this would be faster and easier option to do.